# Can't understand the logic behind a program

Tags: c, vector, normalization

Trying to make a basic C program which finds vectors, I thought I was getting somewhere but I've ground to a halt not necessarily in terms of errors but the logic behind it. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int norm_vec(int *x, int n) {

int i;
float modul;

for(i=0;i<n;i++;)
   {
       modul=++ x[i]*x[i];
   }
       modul = sqrt(modul);

         for(i=0;i<n;i++;)
            {
              x[i] = x[i]/modul
            }
}
```

Comment: Side not: you should make a Vector struct to encapsulate the component array and its count, rather than senselessly passing them around separately like this.

Comment: What value does `modul` start with?

Comment: `modul=++ x[i]*x[i];` What is this supposed to *mean* ? BTW: modul is not initialized (and should at least be a double) Plus: the function does not return a value, where it should return an int.

Comment: you probably mean to do `modul += x[i]*x[i];` instead of `modul=++ x[i]*x[i];`.  Also, initialize modul to 0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me sort out your code first so it's more readable and correct a few mistakes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int norm_vec(int * x, int n)
{
    int i;
    // initialize it at 0 for good practice
    // to my knowledge if you don't initialize a float, it will be 0, but let's stay safe
    float modul = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        modul += x[i]*x[i];
    }

    modul = sqrt(modul);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = x[i] / modul;
    }
}
```

Now to me your code seems mathematically correct. You are first computing the norm of the vector (which you called `modul`) and then you divide each component of the vector by the norm, which is what normalization is.

However, your function is supposed to return an int but it returns nothing. You should decide what to do with it. Should it return the norm, or nothing ?

Comment: "to my knowledge if you don't initialize a float, it will be 0, but let's stay safe" Not a criticism, just an FYI that variables of local scope are not auto initialised In C, and attempting to read them will yield [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have a much easier time by breaking down the problem into smaller parts. Normalizing a vector entails dividing every component of a vector by the vector's magnitude. So you'll need a way of computing magnitude. That's a really common thing to do, so it warrants its own function.

You'll also probably want a way of printing vectors, so that you can see that your functions work as you'd expect. I wrote an example of a print function for `Vector`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Vector {
    int *components;
    int arity;
} Vector;

double squaredMagnitude(Vector);
double magnitude(Vector);
void normalize(Vector);
void printVector(Vector);

double squaredMagnitude(Vector v) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.arity; i++) {
        int component = v.components[i];
        sum += component * component;
    }
    return sum;
}

double magnitude(Vector v) {
    return sqrt(squaredMagnitude(v));
}

void normalize(Vector v) {
    double mag = magnitude(v);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.arity; i++) v.components[i] /= mag;
}

void printVector(Vector v) {
    printf("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < v.arity - 1; i++) printf("%i, ", v.components[i]);
    if (v.arity != 0) printf("%i", v.components[v.arity - 1]);
    printf("}\n");
}

int main() {
    int components[] = {0, 5, 0};
    int componentCount = sizeof(components) / sizeof(*components);

    Vector v;
    v.components = malloc(componentCount);
    memcpy(v.components, components, sizeof(components));
    v.arity = componentCount;

    normalize(v);

    printVector(v);
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `double` for `sum` (instead of `int`)?  Using an `int` limits the size of vector more than using a `double` does, and you're returning `double` anyway.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good catch. I find it questionable that we're trying to normalize a vector with `int` components, in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that too is a valid point.  Hmm; there are multiple levels at which the code in the question  can be criticized.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm just trying my best at demonstrating good code style and program design :p